# Select only newest records from table and make this FAST, how?

Tags: sql, mysql, query-optimization, grouping, groupwise-maximum

Good day, I have a question I'm struggling with a lot, hope somebody already found a clever solution to this (I use MySQL).

I have table like this:

```
Table `log`
----------
id
inserted
message
user_id
```

My goal is to select last inserted record for user and make this fast. Log table is huge (around 900k records),
so my first approach was:

```
SELECT * FROM `log` 
LEFT JOIN `users` ON `users`.`id` = `log`.`user_id`
WHERE `id` IN 
(
 SELECT MAX(`id`) FROM `log` GROUP BY `user_id`
)
```

But it seems it calculate subquery for every row (EXPLAIN shows DEPENDENT QUERY). When I split this query for two:

```
SELECT MAX(`id`) FROM `log` GROUP BY `user_id`
```

and

```
SELECT * FROM `log` 
LEFT JOIN `users` ON `users`.`id` = `log`.`user_id`
WHERE `id` IN (....ids from first query...)
```

It is acceptable to run. Can this be achived by one query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In addition to using group by to fetch the group-wise maximum you probably want to make it an uncorrelated subquery to fetch additional fields for the specific rows from the table.

```
SELECT
  la.user_id,la.message
FROM
  `log` as la
INNER JOIN
  (
    SELECT
      user_id, MAX(id) AS maxid
    FROM
      `log`
    GROUP BY
      user_id
    ) as lb
ON
  la.id = lb.maxid
```

This works best/fastest if you have an index

```
KEY `foo` (`user_id`,`id`)
```

but even without that key the performance is descent.

Comment: It works! Thank you a lot! This is trully thinking in SQL way!

Comment: Keep in mind that I'm not a (My)SQL expert. It's completely possible that someone else will present a far better solution (+pointing out issues with this solution). I took the liberty to change the tags in hope to "lure" (even) more experts into this questions ;-)

Answer (score 4):

How about

```
SELECT user_id, max(id) FROM `log` GROUP BY user_id
```

?

This will get you the maximum id for every user in the log table, all in one query!

Comment: See my answer to speed this up even more.

Comment: But what about the field `message`? That's probably supposed to be in the result set as well.

Comment: Yes, VolkerK is right, I need other fields (like `message`) as well.

Answer (score 1):

If you always are looking for the log for a particular user, partitioning the log file by user_id would speed things up a lot.  If the table is partitioned by user and indexed by id, the query will run very fast.

EDIT: see Dominik's query

Answer (score 0):

In addition, I would make sure you have an index on user_id.

EDIT: generalized